# Advanced CSS Tricks: Capital Initial Letters (Drop Caps) within a CSS3 Multicolumn

Tags: css, layout, multiple-columns

Since about a year the `multicolumn` css3 property matured enjoying support from many browsers. Reason to finally implement it on your website for better design and readability. I thought let's push the envelope and adopt the ancient-but-ever-so-beautiful *Drop Caps* (=first large initial letter) into the multicolumn. **However, *certain screen widths* break the multicolumn layout** in FireFox. What am I doing wrong?

## [**see jsfiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fduCn/)

When resizing the window width, you can see the jumping/breaking of the layout in action in IE and Firefox. Below an example. Stuck on whats causing the defects in the multicolumn miss-alignments!?

---

[image]

---

*Sorry for my beardy alter ego selfportrait: I forgot to shave, was staring all day at this problem with no time to tidy up. I promise you though a clean neat shaved portrait back here once this issue is solved!*

---

[image]

---

Above more alignment problems in most screen widths on Internet Explorer 11. Curious Safari and Chrome show the layout faultlessly at *all* browser screen widths no breakage there.

---

```
#multicolumn {
         column-count: 3;
    -moz-column-count: 3;
 -webkit-column-count: 3;
         column-gap: 53px;
    -moz-column-gap: 53px;
 -webkit-column-gap: 53px;
         column-rule-color: #EEE;
    -moz-column-rule-color: #EEE;
 -webkit-column-rule-color: #EEE;
         column-rule-style: solid;
    -moz-column-rule-style: solid;
 -webkit-column-rule-style: solid;
     column-rule-width: 1px;
    -moz-column-rule-width: 1px;
 -webkit-column-rule-width: 1px;
}

#multicolumn p:first-letter{
    float:left;
    font-weight:normal;
    font-size:44px;
    margin: 7px 1px 0px 0px;
    line-height:27px;
    background-color:#AEE;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @BoltClock for your (layout) revisions! Indeed layout `IS` important!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all I want to say that the use of the multi column layout module is still not recommendable.

Mainly because of the missing support for the `break-before` , `break-after`, `break-inside` properties, with the exception of IE 10+ and the proprietary `-webkit-column-break-*` properties (see: [**CSS3 Multiple column layout**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=multicolumn)).
(You also may want to take a look at my answer to this SO question: [IE (11) improper handling of CSS multi-columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22895282/ie-11-improper-handling-of-css-multi-columns/23001256#23001256))

Additionally you have to remember, that there is a so called "[**multi-column pseudo-algorithm**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/#pseudo-algorithm)", which seems to be confused by your `:first-letter` selector.

You can avoid this problem by using a `span` element with a class attribute for the drop caps instead.

But as the first letters are larger in size than the rest of the text, there arises another problem.
It may happen that a (single) line of text of the beginning of a paragraph with a drop cap may fit to the previous column, whereas the drop cap (which is about twice as high as the normal text) may not.

To avoid this unwanted behaviour you have to use another `span` element, which includes at least more text than that may fit into a single line (of text)!
And giving these span elements a `display: inline-block;` solves this problem.

Just a word about Amir5000 answer: Though my proposed solution also needs some extra span elements, it does not use "purely presentational markup" which may also produce unwanted empty lines.

But as said at the beginning, using multi-column is at least very "tricky" and very difficult to get predicted results across browsers and/ or different viewport widths.

So here is my proposed "solution": [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fduCn/277/)

Comment: Best solution so far.

Comment: +1! great answer @Netsurfer.  I tweaked your "slution" (layout wise) a little: http://jsfiddle.net/53ht8/

Comment: @Sam Thanks, glad you liked the proposed solution! And sure - just "tweak" it according to your needs/ individual case.

Comment: I agree with @Web-Tiki and accepted this answer as the best solution yet. We will probably come back in a year and see what's changed in the landscape of multicolumn support, which apparently, still is in child shoes.

Answer (score 3):

The cause of the issue was the `float:left`on the `#multicolumn p:first-letter`if you take that out you will see it no longer has that issue; However you don't have the same format you wanted with the first letter. So I created a [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/fduCn/3/) where I added

`#multicolumn p {
    float: left;
}`

and added a width for the `#multicolumn` container and centered it as you can see.

Hope that resolves the issue for you.

**-------Update---------**

So after much time trying to get it to flow as intended I was able to come up with a work around that is pretty simple, if you take a look now at the updated [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/fduCn/8/)

I added an empty `span` in between paragraphs to clear the float and also added a media query so it looks nicer on smaller screens

This was the simplest way I could come up with to solve your issue hope that helps!!

Comment: Thanks and +1 @Amir5000 but the whole idea of a multicolumn is ofcourse that it would automatically fill and flow proportionally and evenly through all the three columns... Thanks for the effort of isolating the problem though... this brings us one big step closer to the solution...

Comment: yeah it would be nice, but the float is still the cause of it not flowing correctly anymore. I am still looking at a CSS only solution to get it to flow so I will let you know. Thanks.

Comment: I wanbted to thank you for your genius sparkle <span> idea and since you are new here I wanted for you to have the bounty of 100  points thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about the the column issue. You should make a fiddle for it so that we can help you faster. As far as the first cap issue. This is pretty tricky, what are your constraints? Can you hardcode it look right or do you have to do it dynamically?

I have posted a hardcoded solution here. It is basically just using

```
:before
```

http://jsfiddle.net/emersive/bdAWQ/1/

Comment: thanks will make a fiddle for this indeed! Must be dynamic otherwise whats the point of super-cool-digital-nerdness-and-dynamicness!? :)

Comment: @Britton And where is the "multi-column" in your "solution"!? Imho you missed the topic ..., sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I have Chenges below css

```
p { float:left;}
#multicolumn { line-height: 20px; } /*need for IE browser*/
```

[Demos](http://jsfiddle.net/xspx4/7/)