# IE (11) improper handling of CSS multi-columns?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, multiple-columns

I'm building a 2-column layout using CSS multi-columns, and I want to give a hint as to where to break the columns.

So I say: `columns: 2` on the container, and `break-before: column` on the child where I want the break.

IE (11 in my case) decides to split my content into 3 columns and overflows to the right of its box :-(

Chrome (using the prefixed alternatives `-webkit-columns:2` and `-webkit-column-break-before: always`) behaves nicely.

Am I doing something wrong here ?

Is this a misbehavior of IE ?

Any workaround suggestions ?

Comment: i believe , only IE seems to understant that it has to break here http://jsfiddle.net/JDecq/3/ , set an height high enough and see behavior ... ah , chrome gets it too now and follows column numbers set

Comment: @GCyrillus Thanks. Indeed setting the Height seems to fix IE's behavior, but in my case I need to use the natural height so I can't use this workaround

Comment: i guess what's left is to tell IE to draw 1 col less. http://jsfiddle.net/JDecq/5/

Comment: @GCyrillus Thanks again :) I'm doing something generic here, where I don't know ahead of time if there's going to be a break or not, so I might end up with just one column when I always want 2.I guess I'll just have to give up on break hints for IE - at least it'll be simple and consistent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I am myself very interested in this question I studied the spec and some examples of multi-column layouts.

First I have to say that the spec is horribly "imprecise"!
But it seems that any break definition has precedence over the `column-count` value (though I could not find it explicitly in the spec or anywhere else).

This only happens if, according to the multi-column [pseudo-algorithm](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/#pseudo-algorithm), the respective element, which sets the break point, is already part of the last column (as in your example fiddle).

[The example](http://jsfiddle.net/JDecq/3/) given by @GCyrillus (see comments on question) just works, because the height setting forces the algorithm to first fill the given height before additional column boxes are created in the inline direction.
You can see the "original" effect, if you change the height from 20em to 10em!

So after all, I tend to say that it is not a bug and IE behaves correctly.

At least it might be an error or shortcoming of the multi-column algorithm to not recalculate or refill the columns so that despite any breaks the column-count value is respected. Logically this can only be done as long as the number of defined break points is one less than the column-count value.

As actually IE 10+ is the only browser supporting the multi-column module including the break-xy properties, it is hard to tell if the behaviour is right or wrong and how other browsers will handle this in the future!

For now, I would recommend to not use these properties at all.

Comment: The bug i brought up appears to be with the flex box rules too. IE10/11. Chrome understand differently the rule break-something, that is why the OP is confused i believe :).

Comment: Finally got to read the entire spec, and I agree with your analysis. IE follows the spec, which is not entirely clear on the relation between column count and break definitions. Seems that I was thinking wishfully in assuming the break definitions are "hints" in case that the multicol element can accommodate both definitions - which is why I think the spec is flawed and the webkit implementation is better.